# Django error:view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()

Tags: django

Well i'm new to Django and i'm following outdated course (its free obv) and ran up to this error. What can i change in my code>

Here are codes from views.py and urls.py from both folders:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is teh index view!")


#next one
from django.urls import include, path
from msg import views

urlpatterns = path('', r'^$',views.index,name = "index")


#next one
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from msg.urls import urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('msg/', urlpatterns),
]
```

after trying to makemigrations i get this error :
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Answer (score 0):

It's because your urlpatterns path() syntax is wrong [see](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/)

> path(route, view, kwargs=None, name=None)¶

```
urlpatterns = [path('',views.index,name = "index")]
```

You are using a regular expression in your path, that has been deprecated so you should pick a tutorial that uses that format.

The reason you get the error when running migrations is that the project starts when you run Manage.py and then the app starts immediately afterwards.  The app start does some basic checks and then borks if your have an error in the URLs file.